# Connection to localhost:30000 refused even though I know it's listening

Tags: c, sockets, winsock2

I'm setting up a simple server and client application using C and Winsock2. I managed to make it work one day, but the next day, it kept giving me Error 10061 (connection refused). I didn't change my security settings or anything I thought was relevant.

I can connect to the server using my Web browser by typing localhost:30000 into the address bar. I looked through my code comparing it to the official Winsock tutorial, but nothing seemed to do it.

Since the server seems to work flawlessly, here is the client code up until the part where it fails:

```c
#if defined __WIN32__ || defined _WIN32 || defined WIN32
// define WINVER for MinGW
#ifndef WINVER
#define WINVER 0x0501
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#else
//(this will be for Linux code that I haven't implemented yet)
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <process.h>
#define PORTNUM "30000"
#define BUFLEN 512

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    // Create new SOCKET object
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    // Create socket for client
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    // Initialize Winsock
    int iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        exit(1);
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORTNUM, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    // Attempt to connect to the first address returned by
    // the call to getaddrinfo
    ptr=result;
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("Error at connect(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        scanf("%s", NULL);
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: You don't know it's listening, because it isn't listening, because the error message says so. At least not at that port. Maybe it's listening at a different port. What does `netstat` have to say about it?

Comment: @user207421 Netstat says that the port is listening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but make a small change in following part:

```
    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // <-- Here
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

I think this may be the cause because I found this quote in MSDN:

> The values currently supported are `AF_INET` or `AF_INET6`, which are the
>   Internet address family formats for `IPv4` and `IPv6`. Other options for
>   address family (AF_NETBIOS for use with NetBIOS, for example) are
>   supported if a Windows Sockets service provider for the address family
>   is installed [[link]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2def/ns-ws2def-addrinfoa).

Maybe this part creates your problem.